# Chrome app navigate htmls without creating windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm creating a chrome packaged app, and I need to navigate my htmls without creating a lot of windows, like, if the user click one button, it opens the html in the same window the user are.

Is it even possible? If not, is there a way to make windows modal? So the user can't focus another window without closing the current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packaged apps intentionally do not support navigation. Apps are not in a browser, there is no concept of forward, back, or reload. Applications which do require the concept of navigation, or modal dialogs, should use a user interface framework that supports that functionality. In fundamentals, you can navigate by manipulating the DOM or by using CSS to animate and control visibility of components of your app.

Comment: Like I think, but, is there any way to make a window modal? So the user cant interact with the others windows of the app?

Comment: Only by doing it manually yourself (e.g. disabling all listeners on other windows, or putting a blocking but invisible div over them, and or refocusing your modal window if any other window is focused. Or, creating a modal dialog in HTML instead of a floating operating system level window.

Answer (score 1):

The page you want to navigate to can be opened in a new window, then the previous page can be closed.

```
function navigateToLink (link) {
  var current = chrome.app.window.current();

  chrome.app.window.create(link);

  current.close();
}
```