# Linking to HTML files in chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I would simply like have a link to a different page. But when I use:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 230px; width: 600px; 
   left: 250px; height: 120px"> 
 <h2>
       <a href='cgoogle.html'>
            Sign in with your Google Account
       </a>
  </h2>
</div>
```

The link does nothing. I read that the solution is geturl, but I have no idea how to implement this. Does anyone have an example?

Comment: what you need is to open this in new tab? or in purely new browser??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome app navigate htmls without creating windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198452/chrome-app-navigate-htmls-without-creating-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is open the link in the default browser (note that this may  be not Chrome on the user's system), then add `target="_blank"` to your link:

```
<a href='cgoogle.html' target="_blank">
   Sign in with your Google Account
</a>
```

However, it looks like what you're trying to do here is authenticate the user. The proper way to do that is to use the [Chrome Identity API](http://3-0-1.chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/apps/identity.html). You can read more on Chrome user authentication in general [here](http://3-0-1.chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/apps/app_identity.html) (the API page also has this link).

If all that seems a little daunting, this [app sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/identity) should get you off the ground.

Also note that "link does nothing" is not exactly true: it prints an error to the console, in addition mentioning the `target="_blank"` thingy. When you're developing Chrome apps, using the console is imperative (both the background page and foreground page ones) - it often provides very useful feedback on what's going on.